# How to create a folder named .ssh in the user’s home directory in ubuntu?

Tags: command-line, ssh

I want to create a folder in my home directory which name is `.ssh`. I can't create it with this name because it's showing:

`cannot create directory ‘.ssh’: File exists`

*How should I proceed?*

Comment: As the error message says **directory already exists** and duplicacy of file/folder name is not possible. So, why do you want to create that folder if it already exists?

Comment: I didn't add it earlier that's why I wonder why it saying '.ssh' File exists.

Comment: .ssh folders are made automatically within system for ssh keys. but I wonder why you want to recreate that?

Comment: Oh, my bad, I am a new learner. Someone give me a task to create a folder named as (.ssh) but I didn't know that it is associated with ssh key. Thanks for your help.

Comment: If it is just a task/activity you can create folder named `.ssh(1)` or can choose another directory such as Desktop to create `.ssh` folder

Comment: But his condition is to create it to my home directory only. He also said me to create a blank file named as id_rsa in that folder and change the file permission of id_rsa so that it can only be read by a user. But when I trying to run the command "ssh-keygen" it showing:  Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (/home/arif/.ssh/id_rsa): ----Now how can i do that?

Comment: You can hit enter or enter the file location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to rename the exiting item and then create the directory again:

```
mv ~/.ssh ~/.ssh.bak
mkdir ~/.ssh
```

In addition, usually the tools which use that directory will ask you to assign the following permissions to it:

```
chmod 700 ~/.ssh
```

Thus the directory will be accessible only by the user which is its owner. In addition you can create the directory and set the permission at once by the command:

```
mkdir -m700 ~/.ssh
```

Comment: As the OP said in comments making .ssh folder was just an activity. So removing .ssh folder (which may contain important keys) merely for an activity is what I would not recommend.

Comment: @Kulfy, probably you are right, I've updated the answers.

Answer (score 0):

`.ssh` directory is reserved for ssh keys and configuration.
In case you want to generate your ssh key, execute this command

`ssh-keygen`

and follow the instructions.

Comment: Well, there already is one, so, if you delete it, yet, it is possible, albeit not recommended at all